# What is the most efficient way to add shaped cut-outs in a model?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

I'm trying to model details on the front of an old-fashioned radio, specifically the speaker vents and dial. The issue is I don't know how best to cut these out. The usual method I would use is to add edge-loops and trace the outline of the desired cut-out (from the reference) but this method is both slow and not all that accurate. It also becomes complicated when there are two cut-outs adjacent to each other so the polygons become an increasingly confusing mess of distorted tris and quads.

I also tried the Boolean approach (Difference mode) but again I'd need to clean up all the ngons created by this resulting in the spider-web edges effect. What is the most efficient way to achieve this goal? I get variants of this scenario a lot such as the shapes on top of a beer can or arched windows. Is there a faster route that I'm not aware of?

Thanks

[image: Reference photo]

[image: The mesh. I intend to mirror it as it's symmetrical hence the semicircle. I used Boolean here.]

Answer (score 6):

Begin with a 32 circle, mirror, extrude, then continue to follow the profile:

[image]